# How does React Natives Stylesheet.create work?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

Here is the code for the create method.

```
  create<+S: ____Styles_Internal>(obj: S): $ReadOnly<S> {
    // TODO: This should return S as the return type. But first,
    // we need to codemod all the callsites that are typing this
    // return value as a number (even though it was opaque).
    if (__DEV__) {
      for (const key in obj) {
        if (obj[key]) {
          Object.freeze(obj[key]);
        }
      }
    }
    return obj;
  },
```

How does this function work and what does the <+ operator do?

Comment: `+` is a [variance sigil](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-variance-sigils) in [Flow Types](https://flow.org/)

Comment: For reference, the code above appears in [react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js @ L357-L372](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/073195991bfdf4c96490c65f9c0cf00d09356188/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js#L357-L372)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create<+S: ____Styles_Internal>(obj: S): $ReadOnly<S> {
```

Defines a function called `create` that has a parameter called `obj`. It is type annotated, using [Flow](https://flow.org/) with the following meaning:

- The parameter `obj` is type `S` as denoted by `obj: S`
- Where `S` is of type or a subtype of `____Styles_Internal` as denoted by `<+S: ____Styles_Internal>`. `+` is a [variance sigil](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-variance-sigils) signifying [covariant](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/#toc-covariance) types are accepted (types which are a subtype, along with the type itself)
- The return type is a readonly version of `obj` as denoted by `$ReadOnly<S>`

```
    if (__DEV__) {
      for (const key in obj) {
        if (obj[key]) {
          Object.freeze(obj[key]);
        }
      }
    }
```

[`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterates over [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) and if the value of the property is truthy, the value is frozen by [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze). The value would normally be an object (see [examples](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet) from React Native's documentation on stylesheet) so freezing it would prevent the object from being changed. These things only happen when the `__DEV__`
variable is `true`, which signifies the code is running in a development environment.

I did not author the code, so I can only **speculate** why it behaves like this:

- This behaviour only occurs in development potentially because it could break production apps, based on the [commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/a8e3c7f5780516eb0297830632862484ad032c10) message from the author of code:

> I don't really know if we have/need any safer way of rolling this out than just landing it. It can break if the object passed to StyleSheet.create is mutated afterwards but that isn't a practice anywhere I've seen.

- I don't know why the test for whether to freeze or not is truthiness.
- I'm not certain why the objects need freezing but I suspect it's to remove unintended side effects from mutating style objects as React likely compares style objects between renders by reference.

```
    return obj;
  },
```

Returns the object.

## Further reading

- [Covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science))
- [Subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping)

Comment: This is a good explanation but the code is still confusing to me. If it's not running in dev mode then where does it evaluate the CSS code and apply it in the browser (with return obj??). I'm trying to understand / recreate this feature in my own project.

Comment: It seems like your original question is based on the premise that `StyleSheet.create` evaluates CSS code and applies it to the view. It does not. I think your clarified question is a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) because the answer is long and out of scope of this question; but a simple summary is style objects get passed to the `style` prop on React Native's JavaScript components, it goes through React's diffing algorithm, gets transported across the bridge between JavaScript and native code and native code sets the style on native components.

Comment: The css in Stylesheet.create gets evaluated I think to make sure its proper css code. I'm confused about what mechanism allows CSS to be included in JS files and used.

Comment: There is no CSS code here, only style objects which model CSS rules in a JavaScript object, so no CSS is evaluated. Your premise that `StyleSheet.create` evaluates CSS is a misunderstanding. If a static type checker (such as Flow) is used, there are checks at compile time to ensure values to properties in the style object are valid values for the CSS rule that property is representing. At runtime, there _may_ be checks the values can be set in native code. But I haven't dug into React Native's source to understand that yet.

Comment: Please consider asking a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your current question "How does React Native's `StyleSheet.create` work?" is different from "How does React Native style the view?". `StyleSheet.create` creates a style object, it is not responsible for styling the view. A comment thread discussing this isn't useful for future readers ([comments are not for extended discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365994/the-comments-are-not-for-extended-dicussion)); a full-fledged answer is better but it needs a question from you first.

Comment: Does it just return the input? What is the point of doing that? Do you see why I'm confused.

Comment: Yes, it just returns its input. If you look at the git history, this function used to do more. As to why it does only returns its input now, you'll have to read the commit messages and make some educated guesses In fact, someone has already left a [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/a8e3c7f5780516eb0297830632862484ad032c10#r31485741) asking this on the commit that introduced the change, although it has not received a relevant reply. I suspect why it still exists is to minimise breaking APIs between different versions of React Native.